# How to calculate the complexity of a given code

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity

```
Function(int n)
if(n<=2)
 return 1;
for(i=n ; i>n/8 ; i-=n/2)
 for(j=n ; j>2 ; j=j/2)
  syso();
return Function(n/2);
```

In order to calculate I have done the following :
T(n) = **T(n/2)** + O(1) + 2logn

- T(n/2): the recursive call to the function.
- O(1) : the if statement.
- 2logn: the first "for" will run only 2 times * (the second "for") that will run logn times.

** I have assumed that the second for loop will divide the j by 2 meaning that I will have j/2^k times iterations = logn.

With the same logic the next step:
T(n) = **(T(n/2^2) + O(1) + 2logN)**+O(1) + 2logn
Keep on going until the K step:
T(n) = **T(n/2^k) + O(1) + 2*klogn**

From the first "if" statement the function will stop when n <= 2, therefor:
n/2^k =? 2 > k = log(n) - 1.

Now I place the k in the function and I get:
T(n) = T(2) + O(1) + 2(logn)^2 - 2logn
We know that T(2) = O(1) as it's only doing the "if" statment.

T(n) = O(1) + 2(logn)^2 - 2logn.
Assuming all the steps I've done are correct, is the complexity is O((logn)^2)?

Or I have a mistake in my calculations.

Comment: Big-O notation is **not** algebra. Both loops are log(n), and the recursive part calls that n times. This looks like n log n to me. Constants are dropped.

Comment: Is the line `for(i=n ; i>n/8 ; i-=n/2)` correct? This will evaluate 2 times only, the first time when `i=n`, and the second time when `i=n/2`

Comment: Elliott, so how do I calculate?
I have been to class and this is the method we have learned to calculate the complexity, use the T(n) and run and "open" the next step in the recursive until we get to the K step and then calculate the k in order to get to the "break point" of the recursive function.
Do advice how you reached the calculation that gave you O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a derivation to compliment `Danielle`'s numerical experiment.

---

As `Danielle`'s comment points out, the outer loop only executes twice, once with `i = n` and once `i = n/2`. The inner loops don't depend on `i` which makes things easier.

The loop over `j` will run precisely `floor(log2(n))` times, so, assuming that `syso()` is `O(1)`:

[image]

i.e. your recurrence relation is correct, but the expansion was not.

Applying the stopping condition `n <= 2` to find the maximum value of `k`:

[image]

Math notes:

- A number rounded down differs from its original value by less than 1:

  ```
  floor(x) = x + O(1)
  ```
- The arithmetic series `1 + 2 + ... + n = n*(n+1)/2`.

Applying the above points:

[image]

Which is consistent with what the numerical results indicate.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer!